# Dlink DIR 655 - solid power light, is it dead?

Tags: router, wireless-router, power, dir-655

I have a DLink DIR 655 that recently stopped working. All I can get is a solid power light. I've tried a few flavors of reset (hold down for 30s, hold down, pop out power cord, wait 15s, pop back in, wait 15s).

I'm thinking that it's dead. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @studiohack: Damn, you were right. You should put this down as an answer so I can give you the credit. I swapped it over to a universal power supply I had and it started up. I wonder if it's got some deeper issue that changing the power addressed -- since I put the original supply back and it also started up fine with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yell at it, maybe? or throw it against the wall, and then fix the drywall? just kidding :P.

seriously though, i think it might be *a power supply issue*...glad to help!